# Ruby model | Why is model empty and serializer contains properties?

Tags: ruby, active-model-serializers

I'm very new to ruby and can not understand this situation.

I'm using [active_model_serializers](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/blob/master/docs/general/getting_started.md) to generate model and serializer.
Now after runing

> $ rails g resource post title:string body:string

two files was generated.

1. app/model/post.rb
2. app/serializers/post_serializer.rb

So far so good.

But why is the model object (post.rb) empty and has no properties?

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base

end
```

And why the serializer object contains the properties I defined for a model object? I mean serializer -> component which DO serialization

```
class PostSerializer < ActiveRecord::Base
    attributes :id, :title, :body
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per documentation in [Active Model serializers](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/blob/master/docs/general/getting_started.md)

> The attribute names are a whitelist of attributes to be serialized.

Active Model serializers are means to selectively transform your model into JSON as per API needs, instead of emitting all the attributes of the Active Model model.

Hence, the attributes are explicitly listed in Active Model Serializer classes

Comment: post.rb represents data read or to be written to database. Its an ActiveRecord object, and its attributes and methods are generated by the framework by inspecting "posts" table